# Bash Scripting, taking user input and changing IPADDR0 in ifcfg-enp0s3.conf

Tags: bash, shell, user-input

> ONBOOT=YES
>   IPADDR0=192.168.1.100

```
read -p 'IPADDR0: ' ipaddr
echo "IPADDR0=$ipaddr" >> /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s3.conf
```

So in the above script I'm trying to take in user input and have it replace the IPADDR0 in the ifcfg-enp0s3.conf

The above doesn't seems to work and I can't seem to figure out why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `IPADDR0=<ip>` line is already present in the `.conf` file, then you need just to replace the `<ip>`:

```
read -p 'IPADDR0: ' ipaddr
sed -i "s/IPADDR0=.*/IPADDR0=$ipaddr/" /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s3.conf
```

Comment: No error or nothing. The ip address entered by the user is not being overwritten into the ifcfg-enp0s3.conf "IPADDR0=192.168.1.100" part

Comment: $ipaddr is being printed.

Comment: Use `chmod +w /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s3.conf` to add write permissions to your file.

Comment: If `sed` without `-i` is working, then it's clearly a file write access issue.

Comment: Ah... I have figured what went wrong. A dumb mistake, I was suppose to overwrite the file "ifcfg-enp0s3" but i included a .conf behind.. Thanks for the help! Sorry for the trouble!